# How do I elegantly print the %z (timezone) format in Perl on Windows?

Tags: windows, perl, timezone, rfc822

An offshoot of [How do I elegantly print the date in RFC822 format in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172110/how-do-i-elegantly-print-the-date-in-rfc822-format-in-perl), but Windows specific.

On windows:

```
    C:\> perl -MPOSIX
    print strftime('%z', localtime()),"\n";
```

Yields:

```
    Central Daylight Time
```

I was expecting:

```
    -0500
```

As anyone would on a Linux system.  How can I get the "-0500" on Windows?

UPDATE:

Is this really terrible to do in its place? (Assuming I'm not allowed to install DateTime or package it in any way)

```
C:\> perl -MPOSIX
sub tzoffset {
    my $t = time();
    my $utc = mktime(gmtime($t));
    my $local = mktime(localtime($t));

    return ($local - $utc);
}

sub zformat {
    my ($tzoffset) = @_;
    my $z = '';
    if ($tzoffset < 0) { 
        $z .= '-';
        $tzoffset *= -1;
    } 
    my $hours = floor($tzoffset / 60 / 60);
    my $minutes = $tzoffset - $hours * 60 * 60;
    $z .= sprintf('%02d%02d', $hours, $minutes);
    return $z;
}

print zformat(tzoffset()),"\n";
```

The problem I've noticed is that this returns `-0600` vs `-0500` (which I'd expect), but my guess is that is due to DST calculations or something?  I'm mainly looking for a decent approximation, but I can't figure out why `mktime()` is playing with DST?

UPDATE:

Found out that `tzoffset()` can be much more "stable" in terms of DST if you just manually force DST off.

```
sub tzoffset {
    my $t = time();
    my $utc = mktime(gmtime($t));
    my @tmlocal = localtime($t);
    $tmlocal[8] = 0; # force dst off, timezone specific
    my $local = mktime(@tmlocal);

    return ($local - $utc);
}
```

This way, no matter if you're DST or not, it'll always return `-0500` which is what you want from `%z`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the reason you're getting the former is because

1. `%z` is Linux specific
2. On Windows it's somehow going all case-insensitive on you and picking up upper-case Z instead.

From manpage:

> ```
> %Z    Time zone name or abbreviation, or no bytes if no time
>        zone information exists.
> ```

Also, "%z" seems to be Linux specific - does not work on Solaris either:

```
$ perl -MPOSIX -e 'print strftime("%z", localtime()),"\n"' 
%z
$ perl -MPOSIX -e 'print strftime("%Z", localtime()),"\n"' 
EDT
```

whereas on Linux I get:

```
$ perl -MPOSIX -e 'print strftime("%z", localtime()),"\n"' 
-0400
```

**If you have [DateTime::Format](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime::Format::Strptime#STRPTIME_PATTERN_TOKENS) installed, I think it might suport `%z` based on POD. I don't have it installed so can't test yet**

Also DateTime may support it without the DateTime::Format.

Comment: I think you're right, but I was just hoping to get something decent...  And I did notice the %Z vs %z thing which I thought was kind of ironic as Windows is case-sensitive everywhere, why not strftime() format strings </sarcasm>